# Trying to link CSS to HTML code while they are in separate sub-folders

Tags: html, css

The folder hierarchy looks something like this:

[image: hierarchy]

```
<link ref="stylesheet" href="../css/mainpage.css" type="text/css">
```

This is what I tried and yet it isn't working, I also checked on DevTools and CSS doesn't seem to appear under the network tab so I am guessing there's an issue with the way I am linking CSS to HTML. I am a beginner so apologies in advance if this should be an obvious spot.

Comment: If css folder is uppercase CSS  better use uppercase in your path as well or rename folder lowercase

Comment: It's better to use an absolute path starting from the webroot, instead of dotted directory accessors. So if your webroot is the main folder, then just use `/CSS/mainpage.css`. That way if you have multiple layers of subdirectories, you won't have to count out how many directories you have to traverse.